# EF Core: Delegate passed to HasQueryFilter is only called once when using a configuration class. Why?

Tags: entity-framework-core

If I use a configuration class implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` to set a query filter, and pass a delegate (not an `Expression`!) to this class that is used in the expression passed to `HasQueryFilter`, the delegate is only called once. I found a workaround (see below), but I want to understand why this issue happens. Can someone explain why this is?

The problem is, that the method for the delegate uses a dynamic condition. Because the delegate is only called for the very first request, the query filter will not change even if the condition changes.

Here is an example (see also [the complete test solution](https://github.com/freeboarder42/ef-query-filter-issue)):

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    private readonly Func<int> getMinProductId;
    private static int minProductId = 0;

    public ProductConfiguration(Func<int> getMinProductId)
    {
        this.getMinProductId = getMinProductId;
    }
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.HasQueryFilter(e => e.Id >= getMinProductId());
    }
}

public sealed class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    private static int minProductId = 0;
    
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public DatabaseContext()
    {
        this.Database.Migrate();
    }
    
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options): base(options)
    {
        this.Database.Migrate();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=asp-net-ef-test;Trusted_Connection=true;" +
            "MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Does not work!
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductConfiguration(GetMinProductId));
        
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private int GetMinProductId()
    {
        minProductId++;
        return minProductId;
    }
}
```

This example should return `Product` entities with a minimal ID that is increased for every call. But it does not. The products stay the same every time they are read.

I also tried to put `GetMinProductId` in `DatabaseContext` and pass a delegate to the `ProductConfiguration` with the same result.

The only solution was, to put `GetMinProductId` in `DatabaseContext`, and to pass an `Expression` to `ProductConfiguration`:

```cs
public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<Product, bool>> expression;
    private static int minProductId = 0;

    public ProductConfiguration(Expression<Func<Product, bool>> expression)
    {
        this.expression = expression;
    }
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
    }
}

public sealed class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    private static int minProductId = 0;
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    
    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        this.Database.Migrate();
    }
    
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options): base(options)
    {
        this.Database.Migrate();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=net-ef-query-filter-test;Trusted_Connection=true;" +
            "MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Works!
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductConfiguration(e => e.Id > GetMinProductId()));
        
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    private int GetMinProductId()
    {
        minProductId++;
        return minProductId;
    }
}
```

With this solution the list of products get reduced every time they are read, as expected.

Just to clarify: I am not looking for the approach to define the query filter directly in `OnConfiguring` (which works). I am looking for the reason why approaches with a configuration class that not get an `Expression` passed do not work. Also I would appreciate a solution that uses a delegate.

Comment: First impression: because the function is evaluated once when the model is built, while the expression is incorporated the model.

Comment: Not quite sure. HasQueryFilter gets a LambdaExpression or a Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> passed. This expression gets incorporated into the model anyway. The Call expression in the resulting LambdaExpression should always call the delegate. So the function should be evaluated not only once.